# Google Sheets keyboard shortcut: 'Sort sheet AtoZ or ZtoA' on current column?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, sorting, database

How can I make a Google Sheets keyboard shortcut for both `Sort sheet A to Z` and `Sort sheet Z to A` on the current column (if one does not already exist)?

I'm constantly GUI-header-clicking a pop-up menu to do this on all my "database"-oriented sheets. Adding a keyboard shortcut would save loooooots of time in my Google-Sheets files/tabs.

Are there any easier-to-implement options other than https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros? Is it even feasible to use gsheet-macros for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Google Sheets as of May 2023, per [Keyboard shortcuts for Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110):

#### Method 1: Data->Sort_sheet

The following only works when the pull-down menus ("command menus") are displayed:

- PC: `Alt [+ Shift] + d + s`  (`Shift` for non-Chrome browser)
- macOS: `Ctrl + Option + d + s`
- Chrome OS: `Alt + d + s`

...followed by `a` or `z` to run an ascending- or descending-sort, respectively.

This employs the "Open a menu" keyboard shorcut to open/run the `Data->Sort_sheet->Sort_sheet_by_column ...` menu command.

#### Method 2: Tool finder + keyboard-shortcut mapper

Possibly even better, the following works at all times, even when Google-Sheets menus are *not* displayed:

Run the `Tool finder` (formerly "search the menus") by pressing `Alt + /` (Windows, Chrome OS) or `Option + /` (macOS) and then type `sort (a` or `sort (z` plus `<enter>` to run an ascending- or descending-sort, respectively.

Employ a "keyboard shortcut mapper" utility application (like [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai) on macOS) to map this method to an even-shorter, customized keyboard/keystoke combination.

Comment: "Method 1" was the [answer provided](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/170677/) to you already (credit). While "Method 2" may be a keyboard shortcut to the "Tool Finder" it is not a keyboard shortcut to the sort command.  You didn't specify your OS in your question, and  `mobile/Android/iOS/iPadOS` are off-topic for this site.

Comment: The ToolFinder approach combined with a keyboard-shortcut customizer is the only one that works in all cases, including when the menus are hidden. Further the other answer only works for non-Chrome browsers on PC platform.

Answer (score 2):

To sort ascending by the current column, press **Alt+Shift+D S A**.

To sort descending by the current column, press **Alt+Shift+D S Z**.

See the [keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110) help page.

Comment: Thanks @doubleunary, helpful. These key combos are effectively navigating the `Data->Sort_sheet` menu-command, which works. Alas, the "Open a menu" keyboard shortcut is different on a per-OS (and sometimes per-browser) basis, according to the [above keyboard-shortcuts help doc](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110).

Comment: This answer does not work on my OS. Further, the menu-cmd-based approach does not work in any context when the menucmd is hidden. Thank you for your intput @BlindSpots; I sense that you enjoy stirring up a debate; I will decline further commetns on this question. Best regards.